# Bag of Visual Words: what is a reasonable word (vector) dimension?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, k-means, sift

In the [Bag of Features/Visual Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) paradigm we have a vector `V` in `k`-dimensions, where `V[i]=j` if the `i`-th centroid (obtained by `k`-means algorithm) is the closest one among all the `k`-centroids for `j` visual descriptors (e.g. SIFT descriptors).

AFAIK, the resulting visual vector is very sparse (it means that most of entries are 0-value) since `k` is really big, but my question is: **what is a reasonable value for `k` (and so the vector size)?** Hundreds of dimensions? Thousands? Especially considering that `k`-means execution time depends from `k`.

Comment: Depends on your data. Check some papers what they have used.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data, really. Here is the rule of thumb:

Too small K: your clusters will not represent for all patches.
Too large K: you may get quantization artifacts and probably overfitting.