# PCA resulting dimension in Bag of Visual Words/Features?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, pca

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829213/bag-of-visual-words-what-is-a-reasonable-word-vector-dimension) question I ask what is a reasonable dimension for a vector in the [Bag of Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) model.  since `k` is big and so the number of dimensions is too big to be managed efficiently, PCA is performed in order to reduce the number of dimensions. **What is the usual resulting vector dimension (related to the starting `k` -dimension vector) in such an application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, PCA is **not** used.

Because you then lose sparsity. For performance reasons you want to have sparse vectors, so don't use PCA.

Comment: Ok, so how am I supposed to use (let's say) a set off 1000-dimensions vectors? For example for the Nearest Neighbor problem in order to find the most similar image. I've heard that BOF vectors have thousands of dimensions, while NN algorithms deals with (at most) hundreds of dimenions

Comment: Treat them like *words*. You don't run PCA on text either. Thatjs the point of "visual words", to use text techniques.

Comment: So are you suggesting to use an inverted index, where each word of the index is a visual-word (correpsonding to a certain dimension of our vector)?

Comment: That would be the canonical index for text, yes. And it is fairly standard to have 100000 words in such an index.

Comment: Ok, in such an inverted index, how query are managed? I mean, given a certain image query, we retrieve all the images that contains all the query's words and then we compute the Euclidean/Chi-square distance in order to find the most similar image between all the candidates?

Comment: You get the inverted list for each query term, then join them.

Comment: Ok, that make sense of course, but in this way we don't consider the weight of every word. I mean, if the i-th image patch (word) appears 100 times in a certain image, then it will have the same weight of a image where that same i-th image patch appears only once! Of course this is important, but with the join (or intersection) operation this cannot be modeled. Is that right?

Comment: This is also important for text. Modern text indexes store weight, and even position. So you can have queries such as "A near B".

Comment: I understand. Please, give a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871226/content-based-image-retrieval-cbir-bag-of-features-or-descriptors-matching